# openmp theory vs in-practice efficiency?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

As i increase the number of cores for an embarrasing parallel linear problem (a for loop where each iteration does lots of computation, all independant from the other iterations), the efficiency decreases (efficiency as Ts/(p*Tp) ) somehow linearly respect to the number of cores

i know that in practice thread scheduling, OS, and cache problems can slowdown an implementation a lot.

i can add that i do get speedup, and the problem in theory has linear speedup which in theory 
has efficiency 1 as p increases.

question then: How does the OS, thread scheduling, memory acceses, and other types of technical limitations affect the efficiency of the algorithm as the number of processors increases???? should it affect at all?

Comment: It's impossible to answer, because it depends on the problem and the implementation.  And "acceptable" seems subjective to me.

Comment: added more information so the question can be answered hopefully

Comment: Nope, still too general.

Comment: I can see the changes; see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking about something like [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), but the specifics of each case make it difficult to pin it down.

Comment: thanks, i already took a look moment ago, indeed helps to clarify what happens, however it is still a mystery for me how much memory, OS, and cache affects efficiency for openmp. I would like to know if other people have got linear decrease of efficiency for linear speedup algorithms

Answer (score 1):

You should look into strong scaling:

https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Measuring_Parallel_Scaling_Performance#Strong_Scaling

You basically get diminishing returns as you add more cores to the problem because of all the factors you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, i think this is what is hapenning (diminishing returns). i was used to program in gpus where i didnt see the effect so noticeable maybe because of the types of problems.

Comment: I suggest doing a strong scaling test and then taking the number of cores that produces the fastest result. But keep in mind this will be dependent on the machine

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem CPU bound or memory bound? What is your system architecture - an SMP or a NUMA? How much cache does your processors have? Do you bind your threads to cores or not? ...

There are too many parameters to be considered before anyone can answer your question. I would suggest that you use something like Intel VTune Amplifier or Oracle Collector/Analyzer in order to see where and what causes the increasing inefficiency.